# Why my limit on CPU does not validate via cgroups

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

/etc/cgconfig.conf

```
...

group memlimit {
    memory {
        memory.limit_in_bytes = 8589934592;
    }
}

group cpulimit {
    cpu {
        cpu.shares = 1024;
    }
}
```

/etc/cgrules.conf:

```
@gatewayer  memory  memlimit/
@gatewayer  cpu cpulimit/
```

And I've restarted services via commands:

```
service cgconfig restart
service cgred restart
```

After I execute my python script from user who belongs to group `gatewayer`, I could see the PID when executing `cat /cgroup/memory/memlimit/cgroup.procs` and the limit have been applied on the running process. However, limit on cpu does not take effect, and `cat /cgroup/cpu/cpulimit/cgroup.procs` doesn't print the PID as expected.

I tried to check on the process, and it turns out to be the same result, that memory is limited by cgroups whereas cpu is not:

```
$ cat /proc/18113/cgroup 
174:blkio:/
173:net_cls:/
172:freezer:/
171:devices:/
170:memory:/memlimit
169:cpuacct:/
168:cpu:/
167:cpuset:/
```

Could anyone give me some help? Many thanks.

Comment: `cpu.shares` is not a "limit" on CPU usage, if there's no contention for the CPU. If the CPU is otherwise idle, any process can use the entire CPU, regardless of its `cpu.shares` value. When there is contention for the CPU, however, the `cpu.shares` value is used to determine the percentage of the CPU time that process is given ("this process `cpu.shares`" / "sum of all `cpu.shares`").

Comment: The key problem is that my process **does not** share cpu proportionally as expected with the other processes. I run two same python scripts on different user, one should be guarded by cgroups, the other one is root. cpu.shares is 100 and 1024 respectively. But the processes virtually share cpu equally.  @twalberg

Answer (score 1):

It seems the cgroups setting `cpu.shares` should be correctly applied.

Modern computer usually have a multi-core cpu. The python script used for testing can only use 100% of one core. So if there are still idle cpu cores, the other script could also use 100% from that core.

The better way to test `cpu.shares` is to run a number of processes more than the number of the cpu cores.

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` to indicate the number of cpu cores.